# OpenCV: Extracting Triangles from Delaunay Triangulation

Tags: c++, opencv, delaunay

I am using NetBeans 7.1 on Ubuntu 11.04 and would like to obtain triangles from a set of points using OpenCV.  I build the Delaunay triangulation as follows.

```
CvMemStorage *storage;
size_t      ptIndex;
CvSubdiv2D* subdiv;

storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
subdiv =  cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D( boundRect, storage );
for (ptIndex = 0; ptIndex<numPts; ptIndex++)
    cvSubdivDelaunay2DInsert(subdiv, points[ptIndex]);
```

That part seems to work OK.  It runs and the resulting storage looks like this.

storage 0xb287a90
signature   1116274688
bottom  0x2a2d57a0
prev    0x0 
next    0x2a2e5730
top 0x2cc947d0
prev    0x2cc84840
next    0x0 
parent  0x0 
signature
bottom
top
parent
block_size
free_space
block_size  65408
free_space  0

I have look at the documentation for these functions [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/imgproc_planar_subdivisions.html#subdivdelaunay2dinsert) but cannot find any function for extracting the triangles.

I would be most grateful if someone could tell me how to extract the triangles.

Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate edges like this:

```
CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage();
CvSubdiv2D* subdivision = cvCreateSubdivDelaunay2D(rect, storage);
for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i)
{
    cvSubdivDelaunay2DInsert(subdivision, points[i].Point);
}

cvCalcSubdivVoronoi2D(subdivision);
CvSeqReader reader;
CvSeq* seq = (CvSeq*) subdivision->edges;
cvStartReadSeq(seq, &reader);
for (int i = 0; i < seq->total; ++i)
{
    CvQuadEdge2D* edge = (CvQuadEdge2D*)reader.ptr;
    if (CV_IS_SET_ELEM(edge))
    {
       // TODO: implement some edge related logic here...   
    }
    CV_NEXT_SEQ_ELEM(seq->elem_size, reader);
}

if (storage != 0)
{
    cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);
}
```

Then you can use cvSubdiv2DGetEdge with CV_NEXT_AROUND_LEFT as type parameter it will iterate on the edges from the same facet (triangle)

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry about my slow reply.  I have just noticed your reply.  I have been unable to find the LineSegment variable type.  I was wondering if you could tell me where it is defined.  Thanks very much,Peter.

Comment: Also, how is edges defined?  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Oh, sorry, LineSegment is my internal data structure i forgot to delete it in the example.

Comment: Should the if (CV_IS_SET_ELEM(edge)) block be deleted? Thanks.

Comment: No. You should implement your logic inside the if (CV_IS_SET_ELEM(edge)) block.